# Combined background color and image in shape

Tags: path, svg

I want to set this style for an SVG `<path>`:

```
background-color: red;
background-image: url('myImage.png');
```

This picture has transparent pixels and I need background color to fill it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an SVG object have both a fill colour and a fill pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605078/can-an-svg-object-have-both-a-fill-colour-and-a-fill-pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would do in SVG is to define a `<pattern>` that contains a rect with the color you want and the image you want, and then use that as fill for the `<path>`.

See [this example](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/harness/htmlObjectApproved/pservers-pattern-01-b.html) from the SVG testsuite.

'background-image' and 'background-color' don't apply to svg content unless it's handled by the CSS box model (so basically just the root svg element).

Answer (score 1):

I'm reasonably sure you cannot have an image with a background colour in one path.

You can however replicate the effect by having two paths in the same position, with the image path on top of the solid colour path.